# Cross-Site Scripting: Poor Validation JSP

Tags: jsp, fortify, cross-site

I'm getting Cross-Site Scripting: Poor Validation in my JSP file

```html
<td>${message}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sanitize any input from the user using any AntiXSS library and HTML encode the `{message}` before you output. It's a good coding practice to prevent Cross Site Scripting.

I'm not a JSP coder but a simple search led me to [this OWASP page](https://owasp.org/owasp-java-encoder/encoder/apidocs/org/owasp/encoder/Encode.html). So, the following statement should do the job. You'd need to import the package `org.owasp.Encode`.

```
<td>"<%=Encode.forHtml(message)%>"</td>
```

A more native way to get it done would be to use the [fn:escapeXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) function. With that, your code will look like:

```
<td>{fn:escapeXml(message)}</td>
```

Comment: getting error " Muliple annotations found at this line: message cannot be resolved to a variable , encode cannot be resolved "

Comment: @cheemagenupuri: You'd need to import the `org.owasp.Encode` package for that. Instead, I found that the JSP has hidden features to prevent XSS. You can use [fn:escapeXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) to prevent such attacks. Try this:

`<td>{fn:escapeXml(message)}</td>`

Comment: fortify didn't accept the <td>{fn:escapeXml(message)}</td>